# Three mini-crosswords with maths/physics theme

Tags: mathematics, crosswords, cryptic-crosswords, physics

Three mini-crosswords are presented below. There is a maths/physics theme to these puzzles.

I am sure that they will be solved quite quickly and hints will not be required, but if anyone gets really stuck on something then, of course, hints will be provided as necessary.

[image: three mini-crosswords]

*(NB in case of any ambiguity UK not US spellings)*

Comment: I added the maths and physics tags, and cryptic crosswords for the last one. Hope that's OK.

Comment: @Randal'Thor many thanks - and congratulations on the ever so speedy answer... less than 15 mins..  ..I was not sure which tags to use so just used the crosswords - so I also learnt something from your edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full solution:

> [image]

Thanks to @SOLO for help with Quickish 2 down.

**Cryptic explanations**

> 3 across: MODEL is the first five letters of "Mode lock", and it's used to represent a physical system with equations.
>  4 across: QUARK sounds like QUACK, and it's fundamental.
>  1 down: double def, "intense concentration" and "given by lens".
>  2 down: double def, "poem's rhythm" and "used to measure physical dimensions".

Comment: Ah, beat me to posting by a minute. (But you would've won for the nice graphic anyways.) I think the last one is STATE.